# Toggle style same as class in pure javascript

Tags: javascript

I've got some code where when a button is clicked it toggles an active class. At the same time I need to set a `top-margin` on the toggled element, which also needs to be removed once the button is clicked again and the toggled class is removed. I can't set the `top-margin` as part of the active class as I need to get the value of the margin dynamically by checking the height of another element.

This is the code I've got to toggle the class and add the margin

```
var sizeBtn = document.querySelector(".size-toggle-btn");
var sizeItems = document.querySelector(".select-items");
var elementHeight = document.querySelector(".Detail-Container__inline").offsetHeight ;

sizeBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    sizeItems.classList.toggle('size-toggle--active')
    sizeItems.style.marginTop = "-" + elementHeight + "px";
});
```

However, obviously this doesn't remove the style when the button is clicked again so basically I need to toggle the style just like the active class. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if className is there or not so the code could be:

```js
var sizeBtn = document.querySelector(".size-toggle-btn");
var sizeItems = document.querySelector(".select-items");
var elementHeight = document.querySelector(".Detail-Container__inline").offsetHeight ;

sizeBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if(sizeItems.classList.contains('size-toggle--active')) {
    sizeItems.classList.remove('size-toggle--active')
    sizeItems.style.marginTop = null;
  }
  else{
    sizeItems.classList.add('size-toggle--active')
    sizeItems.style.marginTop = "-" + elementHeight + "px";
  }
});
```